# Регулярным выражением удалить класс из <img>

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Условие: имеются html-теги img с набором классов.

```
1. <img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image">
2. <img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="wp-image alignnone size-full">
3. <img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-large wp-image alignright">
```

Задача: регулярным выражением в PHP удалить из тегов классы, содержащие "align".

Нашел такую основу:

```
<img.*?class="(.*?)"[^\>]+>
```

Как адаптировать?

Comment: например: `<img.*?class="(.*?align.*?)"[^\>]+>` но лучше использовать парсер html и удалять по нормальному

Comment: @matt а проверять вам надо только `img` ? Или другие теги тоже могут  встречаться? Иначе говоря, кроме указанных в первом посту тегов, других тегов не будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проверяются исключительно теги `img`, то будет достаточно поиска по атрибуту `class="..."`:

```
$str = '<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="wp-image alignnone size-full">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-large wp-image alignright">';

echo preg_replace('~\s?class=".*align.*"~', '', $str);
```

Но если кроме `img` могут быть и другие теги, тогда можно сначала отфильтровать именно по тегу `img`, а потом - по атрибуту `class="..."`:

```
$str = '<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="wp-image alignnone size-full">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-large wp-image alignright">';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~<img[^>]*>~',
    function ($m) {
        return preg_replace('~\s?class=".*align.*"~', '', $m[0]);
    },
    $str
);
```

---

**UPD:** Ещё можно использовать подмаски, это наиболее краткий вариант:

```
$str = '<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="wp-image alignnone size-full">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-large wp-image alignright">';

echo preg_replace('~(<img[^>]*)\sclass=".*align.*"([^>]*>)~', '$1$2', $str);
```

В всех случаях результат будет таким:

```
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="">
```

---

**UPD-2:** С учётом уточнений из комментариев автора топика, публикую ещё один вариант решения:

```
$str = '<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="wp-image alignnone size-full">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-large wp-image alignright">';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~<img[^>]*>~',
    function ($m) {
        return preg_replace('~align\w+\s*|\s*align\w+~', '', $m[0]);
    },
    $str
);
```

Результат:

```
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-medium wp-image">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="wp-image size-full">
<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-large wp-image">
```

Comment: спасибо за вариации. Теги могут быть разные и возможно, что классы совпадут. Поэтому лучше применять именно для <img>.  С подмасками хороший вариант. Однако, в конечно итоге мне нужно оставить все классы кроме тех, которые начинаются (содержат) "align". 
 Например `<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image">` преобразовать в `<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" class="size-medium wp-image">`. Ваш код на примере: https://regex101.com/r/1oo58k/1

Comment: @matt то есть, вам надо удалить только слово `align` в классе тега `img` и в любой позиции _(и в начале, и в середине, и в конце)_ ?

Comment: Да, `alignleft`, `alignright`, `alignnone` - где бы они (align*) не находились в классе тега `img`.

Comment: @matt я добавил решение в свой ответ.

Comment: UPD-2 решил вопрос. Огромное Вам спасибо, Эдуард!